# How to use templated class in base class of two different objects

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, generalization

I have problem with storing templates class in the base of two objects.

Say I have generalized class named ObjectManager Defined as:

```
template<typename T>
class ObjectManager
{}
```

And I have a base class like:

```
class MediaSample
{
public:
    MediaSample(ObjectManager<?>* manager){}
private:
    ObjectManager<?> mMediaSampleManager;
}
```

Now I declare another two drived class from MediaSample, say:

```
class AudioSample : public MediaSample
{
public:
    AudioSample() : MediaSample(new ObjectManager<AudioSample>()){}
    //...
}
public class VideoSample : public MediaSample
{
public:
    VideoSample() : MediaSample(new ObjectManager<VideoSample>())
    //...
}
```

My problem is type of **manager**, input parameter of `MediaSample` class.

Which type must be place instead of question mark character? (Audio, Video or what?)

for more clarification i posted complete source of ObjectManager
note that object manager is a poll of media sample objects and media sample can be audio or video

```
class BaseMediaSampleManager
{
public:
    ~BaseMediaSampleManager(){}

    virtual INT initialize(INT objectCount) = 0;

protected:
private:
};

template<typename T>
class MediaSamppleManager : public BaseMediaSampleMnager //(based on user2079303 advise)
{
protected:
    MediaSamppleManager(void);

    MediaSamppleManager(const MediaSamppleManager& manager);

    MediaSamppleManager& operator = (const MediaSamppleManager& rhs);

public: 

    virtual ~MediaSamppleManager(void);

    static MediaSamppleManager<T>* instance();

    INT initialize(INT objectCount);

    // take existing object from object pool and return that object
    INT aquireObject(T** object);

    // take back in use object to object pool
    INT release(T* object);

private:
    std::list<T*> mPooledSamples;
    INT32 mPooledObjectCount;
    INT32 mInUseObjects;
    Mutex mPooledSamplesMutex;
    static Mutex mSampleManagerObjectMutex;
    static MediaSamppleManager<T>* mSampleManagerObject;
};

template<typename T>
Mutex MediaSamppleManager<T>::mSampleManagerObjectMutex;

template<typename T>
MediaSamppleManager<T>* MediaSamppleManager<T>::mSampleManagerObject = NULL;

template<typename T>
MediaSamppleManager<T>* MediaSamppleManager<T>::instance()
{
    if (mSampleManagerObject == NULL)
    {
        ScopedLock<Mutex> guard(mSampleManagerObjectMutex);
        if (mSampleManagerObject == NULL)
        {
            MediaSamppleManager<T>* temp = new MediaSamppleManager<T>();
            mSampleManagerObject = temp;
        }
    }
    return mSampleManagerObject;
}

template<typename T>
MediaSamppleManager<T>& MediaSamppleManager<T>::operator=(const MediaSamppleManager<T>& rhs)
{

}

template<typename T>
MediaSamppleManager<T>::MediaSamppleManager(const MediaSamppleManager<T>& manager)
{

}

template<typename T>
INT MediaSamppleManager<T>::release(T* object)
{
    ScopedLock<Mutex> guard(mPooledSamplesMutex);
    mPooledSamples.push_back(object);
    mInUseObjects--;
}

template<typename T>
INT MediaSamppleManager<T>::aquireObject(T** object)
{
    ScopedLock<Mutex> guard(mPooledSamplesMutex);
    if (mInUseObjects == mPooledObjectCount)
    {
        // do we need waiting until new sample become available? or 
        // is it required to create new sample when no free sample exist in pool? 
        return 2;
    } 
    else
    {
        T* temp = 0;
        temp = mPooledSamples.front();
        *object = temp;
        mPooledSamples.pop_front();
        mInUseObjects++;
    }
    return 1;
}

template<typename T>
INT MediaSamppleManager<T>::initialize(INT objectCount)
{
    if (objectCount<=0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    mPooledObjectCount = objectCount;
    mPooledSamples.resize(objectCount);
    for (int i = 0 ; i< objectCount ; i++)
    {
        T* temp = new T(this);
        mPooledSamples.push_back(temp);
    }
    return 1;
}

template<typename T>
MediaSamppleManager<T>::~MediaSamppleManager(void)
{
    std::cout << "MediaSampleManager Destroyed \n";
}

template<typename T>
MediaSamppleManager<T>::MediaSamppleManager(void)
    :mPooledObjectCount(0)
    ,mInUseObjects(0)
{

}
```

**class MediaSample :**

```
class MediaSample
{
public:
    // create empty media sample
    MediaSample(BaseMediaSampleManager* manager);

    virtual ~MediaSample(void);

    virtual INT32 rate() = 0;

    virtual double frameSize() = 0;

    // data size of media sample
    virtual INT size();

    UINT* data();

    ULONG samplingTime();

    INT32 addRef();

    INT32 release();    

private:
    UINT8* mMediaSampleBuffer;
    // The time sample captured
    ULONG mTimestamp;
    // length of data
    INT mDataLength;

    INT mRefCount;

    BaseMediaSampleManager* mMediaSampleManager;
};
```

**class AudioSample :**

```
class PMCAPI AudioSample 
    :public MediaSample/*<AudioSample>*/
{
public:
    AudioSample(MediaSamppleManager<AudioSample>* manager);

    ~AudioSample();

    virtual INT32 rate();

    virtual double frameSize();

    virtual INT size();

protected:
private:
    // in 8,16 KHZ
    INT32 mSampleRate;
    // Mono or Stereo
    INT mChannels;
    // Used format ex: PCM,G729,G723,G711A,G711U
    INT mCodec;
    // ex : 8 bit , 16 bit
    INT mBitsPerSample;
};
```

Comment: How `MediaSample`, `ObjectManger` and `XxxSample` are supposed to interact with each other? Is `MediaSample`supposed to 'aquire/contruct' `XxxSample` with `mMediaSampleManager`?

Comment: NO,when client need new MediaSample , request it from MediaSampleManager.<br/>
MediaSampleManager<AudioSample>* amsm = MediaSampleManager<AudioSample>::instanse();<br/>
AudioSample* asample = NULL;<br/>
amsm.aquireObject(&asample);<br/>
this way we get Media(audio/video)Sample from pool.
for releasing it we call amsm.release(asample);

Comment: I see, what about the first question?

Comment: Because I don't see the need for `ObjectManager` in `MediaSample` right now.

Comment: MediaSample need to reference it's manager because when client down with MediaSample object , release it.by releasing, MediaSample Object request from manager to take it back to the pool(this down in destructor of MediaSample)

Comment: @Gall MediaSample is base class of Audio and Video Sample.
MediaSample class is ref counted object.like Microsoft Directshow whenever a filter use MediaSample must call addRef(somthing like ref counted object) and whenever a filter done with media sample deRef it.
when ref count reaches zero , we detect this in the destructor of MediaSample object, MediaSample object request from manager to take it back to ready to use pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's can get pretty difficult to mix compile time (templates) and runtime polymorphism (inheritance). What you can do:

a) Make the base class a template

```
template <class T>
class MediaSample {
    ObjectManager<T> mMediaSampleManager;
};

class AudioSample : public MediaSample<AudioSample>
```

In this case `AudioSample` and `VideoSample` will not have a common base class, which may not be what you want. Alternatively, you can

b) Give ObjectManager a non-template base class (an interface)

```
class BaseManager{
    virtual ~BaseManager(){}
    // pure virtual functions that ObjectManager implements
};

template<typename T>
class ObjectManager: public BaseManager{
    // implementation
};

class MediaSample {
    BaseManager mMediaSampleManager;
    // ...
};

class AudioSample: public MediaSample {
public:
    AudioSample() : MediaSample(new ObjectManager<AudioSample>()){}
```

Also, note that if your `MediaSample` constructor accepts a pointer to newly constructed `ObjectManager` and you presumably copy that to the member object, you must remember to delete the pointer or it'll leak. You should probably pass by value instead.

Comment: i test first way but i see no media object constructed.
and about second way i am going to test it now

Comment: What is "media object"? If you mean `MediaSample`, an instance is constructed as a parent of `AudioSample`

Comment: i mean initialize method could not create object of type T.
even when i try to break into the constructor of type T(that is AudioSample or VideoSample class) VS says that source changed

Comment: `VS says that source changed` Is that a compilation error message? Sounds weird, I don't use VS. `break into the constructor` What does that mean? Anyway, your `initialize` method constructs `T`'s by passing `this` to the constructor but you've only shown that `AudioSample` etc has a constructor with no parameters. Did you forget to add the constructor which has a `ObjectManager<AudioSample>*` as a parameter? (I'm assuming that `MediaSamppleManager` is the same as `ObjectManager`. Please, try to stay consistent)

Comment: YES ,both are equivelant
i add defnitions of AudioSample and MediaSample classes

Comment: i found that initialize work perfectly but i don't know what happen when we return from initialize method.after returning from this method none of the created objects are valid!!!

Comment: initialize creates `objectCount` number of uninitialized pointers in the list when you call `resize`. You add the pointers to the constructed objects after the uninitialized pointers.

Comment: Okey,Thank u so much , by removing resize every thing work correctly

Answer (score 0):

How about making MediaSample a template:

```
template <typename T>
class MediaSample
{
public:
    MediaSample(ObjectManager<T>* manager){}
private:
    ObjectManager<T> mMediaSampleManager;
};
```

This way you can have different kinds of MediaSample without the neeed of having derived classes AudioSample and VideoSample.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought the inheritance in the example was to perform this.

Comment: making MediaSample templated class cause us to derive for ex AudioSample from MediaSample<AudioSample> and this is not work

Answer (score 0):

In this case `MediaSample`needs to be a template

```
template<typename T>
class MediaSample
{
public:
    MediaSample(ObjectManager<T>* manager): mMediaSampleManager(manager) {}
private:
    ObjectManager<T>* mMediaSampleManager;
}
```

and `XxxSample` has to inherit from the specialized `MediaSample`

```
class AudioSample : public MediaSample<AudioSample>
{
public:
    AudioSample() : MediaSample(new ObjectManager<AudioSample>()){}
    ...
}
```

Comment: in this case we fall into The **Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)**
when we drive AudioSample from MediaSample<AudioSample> no objects of type AudioSample constructed.
AudioSample is our final type

Comment: @BenyaminJane I don't get what you mean, can you edit your question with the intented behavior you are looking for then ?

Comment: mi mean inheriting AdudioSample from MediaSample<AudioSample> is not correct way as i tested this way before

Comment: This changes the class hierarchy. Presumably there is a reason for the two classes inheriting from the same base.